# Single-Sign-On (SSO) in Java Platform using Active Directory

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, single-sign-on

I need to develop a web application for the Intranet users. I don't want them to enter the login credentials each time they visit the site. It should be automatically loaded from the System Username and Password.

I have successfully implemented functionality which prompt user name and password registered with active directory and validate against LDAP. I need some tips to login directly from intranet website without prompt username & password.

Here is my queries, please let me know your suggestion.

1. Is it compulsory to set SPN?
2. Do we need to create separate keytab file for each client? In my organization, there is around 800 people are working so should I need to add all client principal in keytab file & copy to client machine to perform autologin.

I have tried many API's like JESSO, Waffle, Spring Kerberos, SPNGO but failed to implement auto login.

Comment: You probably need to look in a NTLM java implementation, but I can't help more as I haven't done that, but with a quick search it seam that java already implement this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-auth.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use Kerberos/SPNEGO (which would be my recommendation) you do have to set up SPN. And you only need one keytab for AD domain. Are you running your Java program on some app server, like Weblogic, or as a standalone program? Servers do have security framework that you could use, while for standalone program you'd have to do a bunch of stuff manually.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the easiest way to do this is to use Atlassian's Crowd (https://www.atlassian.com/software/crowd/overview) instead of implementing it yourself. It's a commercial product, but last time I checked, it was dirt cheap, and it just works.